# count documents in pymongo collection

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm a beginner in pymongo and flask and I have a movies collection where an instance of a movie is like :

```
movie = {"title":"Hobbit" , "actors":["Legolas" , "Gandalf"] , "plot":"some plot"}
```

What I want is to find every movie by specific actor name (ex. print all movies where "Legolas" has played) However I am a beginner and I am not very experienced with the syntax needed . 
What I tried :

```
movie_list = movies.count_documents({"actors.$[elem]":request.form['actor']})
        if movie_list != 0:
            movie_list = movies.find({"actors.$[elem]":request.form['actor']})
            return render_template('movie_details.html' , movie = movie_list ) //returns html page that diplays actors
```

I would appreciate your help with guiding me thorugh this simple task . Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try without adding .elem "movies.count_documents({"actors":request.form['actor']})" , you can check this example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of all the elements whose `actor` field contains `"Legolas"` using this-

```py
movies.find( { 'actors': 'Legolas' } )
```

Where `movies` is your collection name.

What if you wanted to find by multiple actor names?

```py
movies.find( { 'actors': { '$in': [ 'Legolas', 'Gandalf' ] } } )
```

You can find more tips and tricks on pymongo's `find` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Now you can simply calculate the `len()` on the returned result.

Comment: so movies.find({'actors':"Legolas"}) works if actors is an array right ?

Comment: @VasilisSkentos it should, but `movies.find( { 'actors': { '$in': [ 'Legolas' ] } } )` will also work

Answer (score 0):

you can get list of movies containing "Legolas" by simply using find.

```
movie_list = movies.find( { "actors" : "Legolas" } )
```

you can checkout this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/) to learn more tips and tricks on querying mongodb arrays.
Above method returns mongodb cursor object so simply you can iterate over to get results.

```
for movie in movie_list:
    print(movie) # you will get movie as dict, so you can get data like  movie["name"]
```